# Azure managed container service (AKS) Static IP

Tags: azure, containers

```
az network public-ip create --name <name> --resource-group <rg name> --allocation-method Static --dns-name <dns name>

{
  "publicIp": {
    "ipAddress": "1.2.3.4",
    ...
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    ...
  }
}

$ kubectl describe svc -n kube-system ingressservice
...
Events:
  Type     Reason                      Age               From                Message
  ----     ------                      ----              ----                -------
  Normal   EnsuringLoadBalancer        9s (x2 over 24s)  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Warning  CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  9s (x2 over 14s)  service-controller  Error creating load balancer (will retry): Failed to ensure load balancer for service kube-system/ingressservice: user supplied IP Address 1.2.3.4 was not found
```

Help? Shouldn't this just work? The IP is in the same resource group.

Is it an issue with AKS? It seems to work for ACS..

Comment: When you say "just works" what do you mean? Don't you have to "associate" the new IP with either a NIC or an load balancer?

Comment: No. It just has to be in the same RG. Then point the yaml config to that IP and it'll auto associate.

Answer (score 1):

So. It turns out that AKS had created another RG besides the one I thought it was in. So moving the IPs to that RG solved the issue.